# Python - np.inf not larger than number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why `np.inf > 1e999` returns False?

I'm using Python 3.7

Answer (score 3):

The notation `1e999` results in a float -- and this float is larger than the maximum possible value. So `1e999` becomes `inf`.

A quick test in Ipython:

```
In [11]: 1e999 == np.inf
Out[11]: True
```